# Responsive Image Gallery with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, gallery

I recently had some help here creating a justified gallery with hover overlay content. It is based on this justified gallery - http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/

I have managed to create everything apart from getting it to be responsive.

I have create a JSFiddle to see anyone can help me.

I've been at this for a week.... hoping I can find the end of my journey here :-)

https://jsfiddle.net/747tgcec/

**HTML** (snippet)

```
 <section id="gallery" class="bh" style="height: 611px;">


<div id="mygallery" class="justified-gallery" style="height: 2398.01027268233px;">

    <div class="single_image" style="width: 350px; height: 260px; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">
        <img src="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Img-2-350x260.jpg" style="width: 350px; height: 260px; margin-left: -175.5px; margin-top: -130.5px;">
        <div class="image_overlay text-center">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="view-bigger">
                    <a class="single_image" href="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery-12.jpg" rel="gallery">Grow Icon</a>
                </div>
                <div class="download">
                    <a href="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery-12.jpg">Download ICON</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.dangoodofficial.co.uk/&amp;text=Check out @DanGoodeMusic"><span>Tweet Me</span>@DanGoodeMusic</a>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>



        <div class="single_image" style="width: 400px; height: 260px; top: 0px; left: 350px; opacity: 1;">
        <img src="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Img-2-400x260.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 260px; margin-left: -200.5px; margin-top: -130.5px;">
        <div class="image_overlay text-center">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="view-bigger">
                    <a class="single_image" href="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery1.jpg" rel="gallery">View Bigger</a>
                </div>
                <div class="download">
                    <a href="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Gallery1.jpg">Download</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.thesaxman.com/&amp;text=Check out @TheSaxManUK"><span>Click to Tweet</span>“Check out @TheSaxManUK”</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>



        <div class="single_image" style="width: 400px; height: 260px;  top: 0; left: 750px; opacity: 1;">
        <img src="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/Dan-Goode-Img-3-400x260.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 260px; margin-left: -200.5px; margin-top: -130.5px;">
        <div class="image_overlay text-center">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="view-bigger">
                    <a class="single_image" href="http://thesaxman.com/wp-content/themes/thesaxman/library/img/gallery/image19.jpg" rel="gallery">View Bigger</a>
                </div>
                <div class="download">
                    <a href="http://thesaxman.com/wp-content/themes/thesaxman/library/img/gallery/image19.jpg">Download</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.thesaxman.com/&amp;text=Check out @TheSaxManUK"><span>Click to Tweet</span>“Check out @TheSaxManUK”</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>

 </div>

    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
section#gallery {
 background-color:
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay {
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
background-color: rgba(1, 62, 187,0.8); 
opacity:0; position:absolute; 
top:10px; 
left:10px;
right:10px; 
bottom:10px; 
z-index:100; 
display:block; 
border:2px solid #bc0001;
border: 2px solid #ffffff
}

section#gallery div:hover>.image_overlay {
 opacity:1;
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position:relative;
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .content {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);font-size:22px;}
section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .content a { color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00)
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .view-bigger { 
position:absolute; 
top:10px; 
right:10px; 
color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); 
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .view-bigger a {
color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00) !important
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .view-bigger a:after {
content:"\f504";
display:inline-block;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
font:normal 20px/1 'dashicons';
vertical-align:top;
margin-left:5px;
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .download { 
position:absolute; 
bottom:10px; 
left:10px; 
color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00); 
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .download a {
color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00) !important
}

section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .download a:after {
content: "\f316";
display: inline-block;
-webkit-font-smoothing: 
antialiased;font: normal 20px/1 'dashicons';
vertical-align: top;    
margin-left:5px;
}
section#gallery div .image_overlay .wrapper .content span { 
display:block; 
font-size:30px; 
font-family: "museo";}



.image_overlay {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: rgba(1, 62, 187,0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
.image_overlay .wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.image_overlay .wrapper .view-bigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
.image_overlay .wrapper .download {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
.image_overlay .wrapper .content {
  font-family: Righteous;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
  font-size: 32px;
}
.image_overlay .wrapper .content a {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
.image_overlay .wrapper .content span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "museo";
}

@-webkit-keyframes justified-gallery-show-caption-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: .7
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes justified-gallery-show-caption-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: .7
    }
}

@-o-keyframes justified-gallery-show-caption-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: .7
    }
}

@keyframes justified-gallery-show-caption-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: .7
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes justified-gallery-show-entry-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes justified-gallery-show-entry-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@-o-keyframes justified-gallery-show-entry-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes justified-gallery-show-entry-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.justified-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden
}

.justified-gallery>a, .justified-gallery>div {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0)
}

.justified-gallery>a>img, .justified-gallery>div>img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0

}

.justified-gallery>a>img, .justified-gallery>div>img:hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
! function(a) {
    a.fn.justifiedGallery = function(b) {
        function c(a, b, c) {
            var d;
            return d = a > b ? a : b, 100 >= d ? c.settings.sizeRangeSuffixes
                .lt100 : 240 >= d ? c.settings.sizeRangeSuffixes.lt240 :
                320 >= d ? c.settings.sizeRangeSuffixes.lt320 : 500 >=
                d ? c.settings.sizeRangeSuffixes.lt500 : 640 >= d ? c.settings
                .sizeRangeSuffixes.lt640 : c.settings.sizeRangeSuffixes
                .lt1024
        }

        function d(a, b) {
            return -1 !== a.indexOf(b, a.length - b.length)
        }

        function e(a, b) {
            return a.substring(0, a.length - b.length)
        }

        function f(a, b) {
            var c = !1;
            for (var e in b.settings.sizeRangeSuffixes)
                if (0 !== b.settings.sizeRangeSuffixes[e].length) {
                    if (d(a, b.settings.sizeRangeSuffixes[e])) return b
                        .settings.sizeRangeSuffixes[e]
                } else c = !0;
            if (c) return "";
            throw "unknown suffix for " + a
        }

        function g(a, b, d, g) {
            var h = a.match(g.settings.extension),
                i = null != h ? h[0] : "",
                j = a.replace(g.settings.extension, "");
            return j = e(j, f(j, g)), j += c(b, d, g) + i
        }

        function h(b) {
            var c = a(b.currentTarget).find(".caption");
            b.data.settings.cssAnimation ? c.addClass("caption-visible")
                .removeClass("caption-hidden") : c.stop().fadeTo(b.data
                    .settings.captionSettings.animationDuration, b.data
                    .settings.captionSettings.visibleOpacity)
        }

        function i(b) {
            var c = a(b.currentTarget).find(".caption");
            b.data.settings.cssAnimation ? c.removeClass(
                    "caption-visible").removeClass("caption-hidden") :
                c.stop().fadeTo(b.data.settings.captionSettings.animationDuration,
                    b.data.settings.captionSettings.nonVisibleOpacity)
        }

        function j(a, b, c) {
            c.settings.cssAnimation ? (a.addClass("entry-visible"), b()) :
                a.stop().fadeTo(c.settings.imagesAnimationDuration, 1,
                    b)
        }

        function k(a, b) {
            b.settings.cssAnimation ? a.removeClass("entry-visible") :
                a.stop().fadeTo(0, 0)
        }

        function l(b, c, d, e, f, k, l) {
            function m() {
                o !== p && n.attr("src", p)
            }
            var n = b.find("img");
            n.css("width", e), n.css("height", f), n.css("margin-left", -
                e / 2), n.css("margin-top", -f / 2), b.width(e), b.height(
                k), b.css("top", d), b.css("left", c);
            var o = n.attr("src"),
                p = g(o, e, f, l);
            n.one("error", function() {
                n.attr("src", n.data("jg.originalSrc"))
            }), "skipped" === n.data("jg.loaded") ? n.one("load",
                function() {
                    j(b, m, l), n.data("jg.loaded", "loaded")
                }) : j(b, m, l);
            var q = b.data("jg.captionMouseEvents");
            if (l.settings.captions === !0) {
                var r = b.find(".caption");
                if (0 === r.length) {
                    var s = n.attr("alt");
                    "undefined" == typeof s && (s = b.attr("title")),
                        "undefined" != typeof s && (r = a(
                                '<div class="caption">' + s + "</div>"),
                            b.append(r))
                }
                0 !== r.length && (l.settings.cssAnimation || r.stop().fadeTo(
                        l.settings.imagesAnimationDuration, l.settings
                        .captionSettings.nonVisibleOpacity),
                    "undefined" == typeof q && (q = {
                            mouseenter: h,
                            mouseleave: i
                        }, b.on("mouseenter", void 0, l, q.mouseenter),
                        b.on("mouseleave", void 0, l, q.mouseleave),
                        b.data("jg.captionMouseEvents", q)))
            } else "undefined" != typeof q && (b.off("mouseenter", void 0,
                l, q.mouseenter), b.off("mouseleave", void 0, l,
                q.mouseleave), b.removeData(
                "jg.captionMouseEvents"))
        }

        function m(a, b) {
            var c, d, e, f, g, h, i = a.settings,
                j = !0,
                k = 0,
                l = a.galleryWidth - (a.buildingRow.entriesBuff.length -
                    1) * i.margins,
                m = l / a.buildingRow.aspectRatio,
                n = a.buildingRow.width / l > i.justifyThreshold;
            if (b && "hide" === i.lastRow && !n) {
                for (c = 0; c < a.buildingRow.entriesBuff.length; c++) d =
                    a.buildingRow.entriesBuff[c], i.cssAnimation ? d.removeClass(
                        "entry-visible") : d.stop().fadeTo(0, 0);
                return -1
            }
            for (b && !n && "nojustify" === i.lastRow && (j = !1), c =
                0; c < a.buildingRow.entriesBuff.length; c++) e = a.buildingRow
                .entriesBuff[c].find("img"), f = e.data("jg.imgw") / e.data(
                    "jg.imgh"), j ? (g = m * f, h = m) : (g = i.rowHeight *
                    f, h = i.rowHeight), e.data("jg.jimgw", Math.ceil(g)),
                e.data("jg.jimgh", Math.ceil(h)), (0 === c || k > h) &&
                (k = h);
            return i.fixedHeight && k > i.rowHeight && (k = i.rowHeight), {
                minHeight: k,
                justify: j
            }
        }

        function n(a) {
            a.lastAnalyzedIndex = -1, a.buildingRow.entriesBuff = [], a
                .buildingRow.aspectRatio = 0, a.buildingRow.width = 0,
                a.offY = 0
        }

        function o(a, b) {
            var c, d, e, f, g = a.settings,
                h = 0;
            if (f = m(a, b), e = f.minHeight, b && "hide" === g.lastRow &&
                -1 === e) return a.buildingRow.entriesBuff = [], a.buildingRow
                .aspectRatio = 0, void(a.buildingRow.width = 0);
            g.maxRowHeight > 0 && g.maxRowHeight < e ? e = g.maxRowHeight :
                0 === g.maxRowHeight && 1.5 * g.rowHeight < e && (e = 1.5 * g.rowHeight);
            for (var i = 0; i < a.buildingRow.entriesBuff.length; i++) c =
                a.buildingRow.entriesBuff[i], d = c.find("img"), l(c, h,
                    a.offY, d.data("jg.jimgw"), d.data("jg.jimgh"), e,
                    a), h += d.data("jg.jimgw") + g.margins;
            a.$gallery.height(a.offY + e + (a.spinner.active ? a.spinner
                .$el.innerHeight() : 0)), (!b || e <= a.settings.rowHeight &&
                f.justify) && (a.offY += e + a.settings.margins, a.buildingRow
                .entriesBuff = [], a.buildingRow.aspectRatio = 0, a
                .buildingRow.width = 0, a.$gallery.trigger(
                    "jg.rowflush"))
        }

        function p(a) {
            a.checkWidthIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
                var b = parseInt(a.$gallery.width(), 10);
                a.galleryWidth !== b && (a.galleryWidth = b, n(
                    a), t(a, !0))
            }, a.settings.refreshTime)
        }

        function q(a) {
            clearInterval(a.intervalId), a.intervalId = setInterval(
                function() {
                    a.phase < a.$points.length ? a.$points.eq(a.phase)
                        .fadeTo(a.timeslot, 1) : a.$points.eq(a.phase -
                            a.$points.length).fadeTo(a.timeslot, 0),
                        a.phase = (a.phase + 1) % (2 * a.$points.length)
                }, a.timeslot)
        }

        function r(a) {
            clearInterval(a.intervalId), a.intervalId = null
        }

        function s(a) {
            a.yield.flushed = 0, null !== a.imgAnalyzerTimeout &&
                clearTimeout(a.imgAnalyzerTimeout)
        }

        function t(a, b) {
            s(a), a.imgAnalyzerTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                u(a, b)
            }, .001), u(a, b)
        }

        function u(b, c) {
            for (var d, e = b.settings, f = b.lastAnalyzedIndex + 1; f <
                b.entries.length; f++) {
                var g = a(b.entries[f]),
                    h = g.find("img");
                if (h.data("jg.loaded") === !0 || "skipped" === h.data(
                    "jg.loaded")) {
                    d = f >= b.entries.length - 1;
                    var i = b.galleryWidth - (b.buildingRow.entriesBuff
                            .length - 1) * e.margins,
                        j = h.data("jg.imgw") / h.data("jg.imgh");
                    if (i / (b.buildingRow.aspectRatio + j) < e.rowHeight &&
                        (o(b, d), ++b.yield.flushed >= b.yield.every))
                        return void t(b, c);
                    b.buildingRow.entriesBuff.push(g), b.buildingRow.aspectRatio +=
                        j, b.buildingRow.width += j * e.rowHeight, b.lastAnalyzedIndex =
                        f
                } else if ("error" !== h.data("jg.loaded")) return
            }
            b.buildingRow.entriesBuff.length > 0 && o(b, !0), b.spinner
                .active && (b.spinner.active = !1, b.$gallery.height(b.$gallery
                        .height() - b.spinner.$el.innerHeight()), b.spinner
                    .$el.detach(), r(b.spinner)), s(b), b.$gallery.trigger(
                    c ? "jg.resize" : "jg.complete")
        }

        function v(a) {
            function b(a) {
                if ("string" != typeof d.sizeRangeSuffixes[a]) throw "sizeRangeSuffixes." +
                    a + " must be a string"
            }

            function c(a, b) {
                if ("string" == typeof a[b]) {
                    if (a[b] = parseFloat(a[b], 10), isNaN(a[b]))
                        throw "invalid number for " + b
                } else {
                    if ("number" != typeof a[b]) throw b +
                        " must be a number";
                    if (isNaN(a[b])) throw "invalid number for " +
                        b
                }
            }
            var d = a.settings;
            if ("object" != typeof d.sizeRangeSuffixes) throw "sizeRangeSuffixes must be defined and must be an object";
            if (b("lt100"), b("lt240"), b("lt320"), b("lt500"), b(
                    "lt640"), b("lt1024"), c(d, "rowHeight"), c(d,
                    "maxRowHeight"), d.maxRowHeight > 0 && d.maxRowHeight <
                d.rowHeight && (d.maxRowHeight = d.rowHeight), c(d,
                    "margins"), "nojustify" !== d.lastRow && "justify" !==
                d.lastRow && "hide" !== d.lastRow) throw 'lastRow must be "nojustify", "justify" or "hide"';
            if (c(d, "justifyThreshold"), d.justifyThreshold < 0 || d.justifyThreshold >
                1) throw "justifyThreshold must be in the interval [0,1]";
            if ("boolean" != typeof d.cssAnimation) throw "cssAnimation must be a boolean";
            if (c(d.captionSettings, "animationDuration"), c(d,
                    "imagesAnimationDuration"), c(d.captionSettings,
                    "visibleOpacity"), d.captionSettings.visibleOpacity <
                0 || d.captionSettings.visibleOpacity > 1) throw "captionSettings.visibleOpacity must be in the interval [0, 1]";
            if (c(d.captionSettings, "nonVisibleOpacity"), d.captionSettings
                .visibleOpacity < 0 || d.captionSettings.visibleOpacity >
                1) throw "captionSettings.nonVisibleOpacity must be in the interval [0, 1]";
            if ("boolean" != typeof d.fixedHeight) throw "fixedHeight must be a boolean";
            if ("boolean" != typeof d.captions) throw "captions must be a boolean";
            if (c(d, "refreshTime"), "boolean" != typeof d.randomize)
                throw "randomize must be a boolean"
        }
        var w = {
            sizeRangeSuffixes: {
                lt100: "_t",
                lt240: "_m",
                lt320: "_n",
                lt500: "",
                lt640: "_z",
                lt1024: "_b"
            },
            rowHeight: 120,
            maxRowHeight: 0,
            margins: 1,
            lastRow: "nojustify",
            justifyThreshold: .75,
            fixedHeight: !1,
            waitThumbnailsLoad: !0,
            captions: !0,
            cssAnimation: !1,
            imagesAnimationDuration: 500,
            captionSettings: {
                animationDuration: 500,
                visibleOpacity: .7,
                nonVisibleOpacity: 0
            },
            rel: null,
            target: null,
            extension: /\.[^.\\/]+$/,
            refreshTime: 100,
            randomize: !1
        };
        return this.each(function(c, d) {
            var e = a(d);
            e.addClass("justified-gallery");
            var f = e.data("jg.context");
            if ("undefined" == typeof f) {
                if ("undefined" != typeof b && null !== b &&
                    "object" != typeof b) throw "The argument must be an object";
                var g = a(
                    '<div class="spinner"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>'
                );
                f = {
                    settings: a.extend({}, w, b),
                    imgAnalyzerTimeout: null,
                    entries: null,
                    buildingRow: {
                        entriesBuff: [],
                        width: 0,
                        aspectRatio: 0
                    },
                    lastAnalyzedIndex: -1,
                    "yield": {
                        every: 2,
                        flushed: 0
                    },
                    offY: 0,
                    spinner: {
                        active: !1,
                        phase: 0,
                        timeslot: 150,
                        $el: g,
                        $points: g.find("span"),
                        intervalId: null
                    },
                    checkWidthIntervalId: null,
                    galleryWidth: e.width(),
                    $gallery: e
                }, e.data("jg.context", f)
            } else if ("norewind" === b)
                for (var h = 0; h < f.buildingRow.entriesBuff.length; h++)
                    k(f.buildingRow.entriesBuff[h], f);
            else f.settings = a.extend({}, f.settings, b), n(f); if (
                v(f), f.entries = e.find("> a, > div:not(.spinner)")
                .toArray(), 0 !== f.entries.length) {
                f.settings.randomize && (f.entries.sort(function() {
                    return 2 * Math.random() - 1
                }), a.each(f.entries, function() {
                    a(this).appendTo(e)
                }));
                var i = !1;
                a.each(f.entries, function(b, c) {
                    var d = a(c),
                        g = d.find("img");
                    if (g.data("jg.loaded") !== !0 &&
                        "skipped" !== g.data("jg.loaded")) {
                        null !== f.settings.rel && d.attr(
                                "rel", f.settings.rel),
                            null !== f.settings.target && d
                            .attr("target", f.settings.target);
                        var h = "undefined" != typeof g.data(
                            "safe-src") ? g.data(
                            "safe-src") : g.attr("src");
                        g.data("jg.originalSrc", h), g.attr(
                            "src", h);
                        var j = parseInt(g.attr("width"),
                                10),
                            k = parseInt(g.attr("height"),
                                10);
                        if (f.settings.waitThumbnailsLoad !==
                            !0 && !isNaN(j) && !isNaN(k))
                            return g.data("jg.imgw", j), g.data(
                                    "jg.imgh", k), g.data(
                                    "jg.loaded", "skipped"),
                                t(f, !1), !0;
                        g.data("jg.loaded", !1), i = !0, f.spinner
                            .active === !1 && (f.spinner.active = !
                                0, e.append(f.spinner.$el),
                                e.height(f.offY + f.spinner
                                    .$el.innerHeight()), q(
                                    f.spinner));
                        var l = new Image,
                            m = a(l);
                        m.one("load", function() {
                            g.off("load error"), g.data(
                                "jg.imgw", l.width
                            ), g.data("jg.imgh",
                                l.height), g.data(
                                "jg.loaded", !0
                            ), t(f, !1)
                        }), m.one("error", function() {
                            g.off("load error"), g.data(
                                "jg.loaded",
                                "error"), t(f, !
                                1)
                        }), l.src = h
                    }
                }), i || t(f, !1), p(f)
            }
        })
    }
}(jQuery);
```